# Check Facelets files integrity during build or deployment

Tags: jsf, jboss, facelets

Is there any way to check your Facelets files for errors during the build or deployment process?

I am not looking for a solution that will simply validate the Facelets files against their schema, but also to verify that EL expressions are valid. For example if the name of a property or method is misspelled in a EL expression (eg. `Value=”#{controller.nme}”` instead of `value="#{controller.name}"`), this will be discovered only during testing at run time.

I am using JBoss 7.1.

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically Eclipse plugins like WTP and JBosd tools can do this, but as of today those only work in the full IDE, not as a seperate command line tool that can be invoked by Ant or Maven.

Worse, those tools have never been perfect. They always report tons of false positives and as a rule of thumb their validation algorithms are usually years behind. The current version of WTP probably just barely validates everything from Java EE 5 (maybe it still misses some obscure feautures).

As a result, if you fail your build based on this validation you'll probably never be able to deploy anything. Even in the most carefully coded and fully correct web apps, WTP and JBoss tools find it necessary to report hundreds or in large projects thousands of warnings and errors. It's IMHO completely useless to depend upon.

Comment: Agreed, the basic checking offered by tools like WTP and JBoss Tools won't be useful breaking the build. But JSFUnit tests maybe would. :)

Comment: Indeed, those, maybe even
Selenium, would do a much better job. There is btw a subset of EL and XHTML that can be validated in theory, but WTP just sucks even at that. For other things, tags need to become more expressive, eg allowing to declare what variables they insert in what scope in order to validate them.

Answer (score 3):

This is a sort of a chicken/egg problem. As you said yourself, many EL expressions can only be evaluated at run time.

<sub>Keep in mind that EL includes a whole lot more than simple property and method names, it has different implicit objects (`params`, `facesContext`, `session`, etc) which are available in different contexts, and you can also add your own objects to that through many different ways (other Facelets templates, beans which may or may not be registered in the faces-config and even plain Java code inserting objects in the view).</sub>

All these things contribute to make very hard to build tooling with this type of checking for you. I think the closest thing for what you want would be to create your own JSF unit tests for each page using [JSFUnit](http://www.jboss.org/jsfunit) and [Arquillian](http://www.jboss.org/arquillian.html) and integrate them to your build. As you are targeting JBoss 7, I think that should be feasible.